# How can I perform this array-slicing and multiplication operation more efficiently?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, multiplication

I used the last two dimensions of this 3D matrix as a 2D matrix. So I just wanna multiply the 2D matrix from the result of `Matrix1(i,:,:)` (which `i`-by-`i`) with the vector `Matrix2(i,:).')` (which is `1`-by-`i`).

The only way I could do that was using an auxiliary matrix that picked up all the numbers from the 2 dimensions from the 3D matrix:

```
matrixAux(:,:) = Matrix1(1,:,:)
```

and then I did the multiplication:

```
matrixAux * (Matrix2(i,:).')
```

and it worked. However, this is slow because I need to copy all the 3D matrix to a lot of auxiliary matrices, and I need to speed up my code because I'm doing the same operation many times.

How can I do that more efficiently, without having to copy the matrix?

Comment: Just curious if the solution provided here worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

## Approach I: `bsxfun` Multiplication

One approach would be to use the output of `bsxfun` with `@times` whose values you can use instead of calculating the matrix multiplication results in a loop -

```
sum(bsxfun(@times,Matrix1,permute(Matrix2,[1 3 2])),3).'
```

**Example**

As an example, let's suppose `Matrix1` and `Matrix2` are defined like this -

```
nrows = 3;
p = 6;
ncols = 2;

Matrix1 = rand(nrows,ncols,p)
Matrix2 = rand(nrows,p)
```

Then, you have your loop like this -

```
for i = 1:size(Matrix1,1)
    matrixAux(:,:) = Matrix1(i,:,:);
    matrix_mult1 = matrixAux * (Matrix2(i,:).') %//'
end
```

So, instead of the loops, you can directly calculate the matrix multiplication results -

```
matrix_mult2 = sum(bsxfun(@times,Matrix1,permute(Matrix2,[1 3 2])),3).'
```

Thus, each column of `matrix_mult2` would represent `matrix_mult1` at each iteration of the loop, as the output of the codes would make it clearer -

```
matrix_mult1 =
    0.7693
    0.8690
matrix_mult1 =
    1.0649
    1.2574
matrix_mult1 =
    1.2949
    0.6222
matrix_mult2 =
    0.7693    1.0649    1.2949
    0.8690    1.2574    0.6222
```

---

## Approach II: "Full" Matrix Multiplication

Now, this must be exciting! Well you can also leverage MATLAB's fast matrix multiplication to get your intermediate matrix multiplication results again without loops. If `Matrix1` is `nrows x p x ncols`, you can reshape it to `nrows*p x ncols` and then perform matrix multiplication of it with `Matrix2`. Then, to get an equivalent of `matrix_mult2`, you need to select indices from the multiplication result. This is precisely achieved here -

```
%// Get size of Matrix1 to be used regularly inside the codes later on
[m1,n1,p1] = size(Matrix1);

%// Convert 3D Matrix1 to 2D and thus perform "full" matrix multiplication 
fmult = reshape(Matrix1,m1*n1,p1)*Matrix2'; %//'

%// Get valid indices
ind = bsxfun(@plus,[1:m1:size(fmult,1)]',[0:nrows-1]*(size(fmult,1)+1)); %//'
 
%// Get values from the full matrix multiplication result
matrix_mult3 = fmult(ind);
```

Here, `matrix_mult3` must be the same as `matrix_mult2`.

**Observations:** Since we are not using all the values calculated from the full matrix multiplication, rather indexing into it and selecting few of its elements, as such this approach performs better than the other approaches under certain circumstances. This approach seems to be the best one when `nrows` is a small value as we would be using more number of elements from the full matrix multiplication output in that case.

---

## Benchmark Results

Two cases were tested against the three approaches and the test results seem to support our hypotheses discussed earlier.

**Case 1**

`Matrix 1` as `400 x 400 x 400`, the runtimes are -

```
--------------- With Loops
Elapsed time is 2.253536 seconds.
--------------- With BSXFUN
Elapsed time is 0.910104 seconds.
--------------- With Full Matrix Multiplication
Elapsed time is 4.361342 seconds.
```

**Case 2**

`Matrix 1` as `40 x 2000 x 2000`, the runtimes are -

```
--------------- With Loops
Elapsed time is 5.402487 seconds.
--------------- With BSXFUN
Elapsed time is 2.585860 seconds.
--------------- With Full Matrix Multiplication
Elapsed time is 1.516682 seconds.
```